# Lightning init handler called multiple times

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

We have a lightning component thats being used a quick action. When the lightning component is activated it calls the init handler multiple times

> Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="CloneObject">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="name" type="String"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <ui:inputText label="Quote Name" value="{!v.name}"/>
    <br/>
    <ui:button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" press="{!c.clone}" label="Clone" />
</aura:component>
```

> js controller

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.doInit");
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    console.log(recordId);
    action.setParams({
        "recordId" : recordId
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(component.isValid() && state == "SUCCESS"){
            component.set("v.name", response.getReturnValue());
        } else {
            console.log('There was a problem and the state is: '+state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

clone : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.cloneQuote");
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    console.log('record Id');
    console.log(recordId);
    action.setParams({
        "objectId": recordId,
        "cloneAttachments": true
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(component.isValid() && state == "SUCCESS"){
            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            urlEvent.setParams({
                "url": "/" + response.getReturnValue()
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
        } else {
            console.log('There was a problem and the state is: '+state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

> Apex Controller

```
public class CloneObject {

    @auraEnabled
    public static String doInit(String recordId) {
        return [SELECT Name FROM Quote WHERE Id = :recordId].Name;
    }
 }
```

> Output when the quickaction is clicked

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try do rename you Apex controller static method to something other than 'doInit'

Comment: @benahm that is fascinating. I figured it would be best practice to continue out the method name from component -> controller -> apex method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I marked it as a possible dupe of [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163600/lightning-component-close-case-button-not-working/163603#163603) question, but here is the answer.

You cannot name the Apex Component method identically to the Lightning Controller method. Not sure why, but it creates recursion (as you've seen in your logs).

Change either of them and you'll be fine.